# Font-awesome not working with webpack and cordova

Tags: cordova, webpack, font-awesome, reactjs

I have installed font-awesome-webpack via npm in my Cordova project. I use webpack to create a bundle.js-file to my /www-folder. For the fonts to work I also have to build the font-awesome-files to this folder. My wepack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
       app: ["./src/main.jsx"]
    },
    output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/cwebphone/www"),
       publicPath: "http://localhost:8088/",
       filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [
       new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
       new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [{
         test: /\.js?$/,
         loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         include: __dirname
    },
    { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' },
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
    { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader", query: { mimetype: "image/png"}},
    { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
    { test: /\.(otf|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
    {
    test: /\.jsx$/,
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    include: __dirname
  }
  ]
 }
};
```

In my main.jsx I have this require for Font-awesome-webpack:

```js
require("font-awesome-webpack!../node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/font-awesome.config.js");
```

The files that do get built is the .woff, .woff2, .svg, .eot and a .ttf-file. The font-awesome-folder also contains one otf-file that does not get built. Do anyone know what I am missing to get this to work?